# Is it possible to change the CSS style of a website loaded into a frame?

Tags: html, css, iframe, stylesheet

I am a new web designer creating a website for a realtor, and I using a URL provided to me with a listing of homes to display. I put the URL in as an iframe src and I am getting the results listing on the page, but I don't like the way the list looks. Is there a way to override the stylesheet for the website in the iframe so I can use my own?

Comment: Before you attempt to tackle this problem, please read about same origin policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy .

It will save you lot of time.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Answer (score 0):

If the `<iframe>` is from the same domain, the elements are easily accessible via javascript/jquery

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").removeClass("redBG");
```

But you cannot override styles of iframe content by using you own css alone.

Comment: While technically true, this is probably not helpful if the OP wants to apply more than a couple one-off style changes.